# Tailwindcss Dark Mode - custom parent tag

Tags: css, tailwind-css, darkmode

I am using tailwind in a widget that in the end is attached to a shadow-dom node on different websites.

I am using TailwindCSSs class implementation of the dark mode (  darkMode: 'class') which unfortunately attaches a "dark" class to html-tag.

Is it possible to define different tag to attach the "dark" class to? I do not want to mess up the code of the websites I am adding my widget to.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using small amount of tailwind classes, try using [a prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix). But you have to add prefix for every tailwind classes - such as `tw-bg-black tw-text-white tw-font-bold` etc.